# TypeError: expected string or buffer - Пытаюсь обновить запись в БД через update_or_create с использованием choices

Tags: python, django

Модели

```
class Showtimes(models.Model):

    active_status = 1
    deactivated_status = 2

    status_choices = (
        (active_status, 'Active'),
        (deactivated_status, 'Deactivated'),
    )

    buy_ticket_url = models.URLField('Buy ticket URL', max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Show start date-time')
    status = models.IntegerField('Showtime Status', choices=status_choices, default=active_status)

    showtime_show = models.ForeignKey(Shows, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Show name')
    showtime_place = models.ForeignKey('app_places.Places', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Place')

class ShowtimeMovies(Showtimes):
    movie_format = models.CharField('Movie Format', max_length=10, blank=True)
```

Кусок кода, где возникает ошибка (строка status='active_status')

```
ShowtimeMovies.objects.update_or_create(
    showtime_place=get_cinema,
    showtime_show=get_movie,
    date_time=date_time,
    defaults=dict(
        buy_ticket_url=buy_ticket_url,
        movie_format=show_format,
        status='active_status')
```

Пробовал менять статус на active_status, Active, 'Active', 1 - ничего не помогает. Пробовал проимпортировать класс модели в модуль, где код выполняется. С Чёйсами первый раз имею дело. Что делаю не так?

---

**Решение проблемы.**

Шаг 1.

Ввиду того, что создается инстанс дочерней модели, то нужно было

```
active_status = 1
deactivated_status = 2

status_choices = (
    (active_status, 'Active'),
    (deactivated_status, 'Deactivated'),
)
```

перенести из Showtimes в ShowtimeMovies.

Шаг 2.

Заменить строку 
`status='active_status'` на `status=ShowtimeMovies.active_status`, как и было предложено Алексеем ниже.
В итоге получаем:

```
ShowtimeMovies.objects.update_or_create(
    showtime_place=get_cinema,
    showtime_show=get_movie,
    date_time=date_time,
    defaults=dict(
        buy_ticket_url=buy_ticket_url,
        movie_format=show_format,
        status=ShowtimeMovies.active_status)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых что за defaults? У вас нет такого поля в моделе. А атрибут default в классе Models содержит значение данного поля по умолчанию (то-есть если его не задавать при создании - в объект будет автоматически подставлено значение default)

Во вторых если вам нужно задать статус используя choise, это будет выглядеть так:

```
status = ShowtimeMovies.active_status
```

только я настоятельно рекомендую именовать константы в UPPER_CASE, то есть заменить active_status и deactivated_status на ACTIVE_STATUS и DEACTIVE_STATUS соответственно. Это будет более правильно, так вам будет проще работать с другими Python разработчиками, и избавит вас от путаницы ведь константу в lower_case можно перепутать с атрибутом или методом класса.

Весь ваш код судя по всему должен выглядеть так:

```
ShowtimeMovies.objects.update_or_create(
    showtime_place=get_cinema,
    showtime_show=get_movie,
    date_time=date_time,
    buy_ticket_url=buy_ticket_url,
    movie_format=show_format,
    status=ShowtimeMovies.active_status
)
```

Comment: Ну во первых что за defaults? - Функция update_or_create имеет атрибут defaults, в котором в виде словаря указываются поля, которые нужно обновить в случае, если имеется запись  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create, внизу есть пример - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115318/create-django-model-or-update-if-exists . Ваш вариант выдает app_show.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ShowtimeMovies -- it returned 24! , поэтому и используется defaults - найти place, show, date_time и если найдено, то обновить url, формат, статус

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали направление. Получилось решить проблему.

Comment: Отстал от жизни. Я читал доки целиков к Django 1.4, а это относительно новая тема, срочно нужно перечитывать.